# Weaker Condition than Differentiability that Implies Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

It is a well-known fact that differentiability implies continuity.  My question is this: is there some condition for a function that is both weaker than differentiability and stronger than continuity?  I.e., is there a condition that "guarantees" continuity that does not also guarantee differentiability?

**Edit:** I realized immediately after posting this that I did not give enough thought to asking this question.  The question that I meant to ask (which, I think, is more interesting) is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833239/differentiability-related-condition-that-implies-continuity).

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for: Real functions which are convex on an interval are continuous on that interval. They are also differentiable almost everywhere though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several, at least on a bounded interval, you have

Differentiability $\Rightarrow$ Lipschitz continuity $\Rightarrow$ Hölder continuity (with decreasing exponent) $\Rightarrow$ Absolute continuity $\Rightarrow$ continuity

which are some of the ones that are used more often.

Answer (score 12):

A function $f$ is called [Lipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) continuous if there is a (uniform) constant $K$ such that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le K |x - y|$$

for all $x, y$ in the domain of $f$ (alternatively, you can define a function to be locally Lipschitz if for each compact subset of the domain such a constant exists). Lipschitz continuity implies continuity (and in fact *uniform* continuity), but it does not imply differentiability - as a slightly trivial example, $|x|$ is Lipschitz but not differentiable at $0$. Being Lipschitz does imply differentiability almost everywhere, though (and in fact, $f' \in L^{\infty}$).

Alternatively, you can consider [absolute continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_continuous), which again implies differentiability only almost everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, there's [Lipschitz continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).

Answer (score 3):

For one, **Holder continuity**. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition).