# Differentiability-Related Condition that Implies Continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity

I previously asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833201/weaker-condition-than-differentiability-that-implies-continuity/833208#833208) that I did not phrase as I intended.  This is a revision of that question:

It is a well-known fact that differentiability implies continuity.  And, for example, the existence and continuity of first partial derivatives implies continuity; but it also implies differentiability.

**My question is this: is there some *differentiability-related* condition for a function that is both weaker than differentiability and stronger than continuity?**

By "differentiability-related" I mean "involving the partial derivatives of various orders of the given function" (or any other conditions that you can think of that closely approximate whatever "differentiability-related" might mean, were it to be better defined.)

Comment: Does the condition "to have locally bounded partial derivatives" meets the requirement?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this property's consequences.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: This property implies continuity. This is proved in a similar (but simpler) way as the theorem "continuous partial derivatives implies differentiability".